# Flutter ListView animate items on gestures

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve some animation feedback on a listview where when a user taps down on a list item it scales down to say 90% and when tapped back up returns to 100%. The problem is that in order to update a state on a variable holding the scale value, all the list items update to that new scale. Any solutions to this?

Comment: Can you share your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use StatefulBuilder to setState only for the list item that is tapped.
2. OnTap change the scale value in setState().

### Following is the working code for your reference:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: DemoWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class DemoWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('FlutterApp'),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 10,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          double scale = 1;
          return StatefulBuilder(
            builder: (BuildContext context, StateSetter setState) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Transform.scale(
                    scale: scale,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Text(index.toString()),
                      color: Colors.amberAccent,
                    )),
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    scale = scale == 1 ? 0.9 : 1;
                  });
                },
              );
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I hope this helps you, in case of any doubt please comment. ***In case this works for you please accept and up-vote this answer.***

Comment: What I did was take each item and made it it's own statefull widget that way I can create a animation controller for each item on its own!

Comment: it does not go back to full size when tapping up, also the items are not animated at al

Comment: And if you have problem with animations then please ask another question for that and give me link in comment..

Comment: full code? sure: https://pastebin.com/raw/nr9qex92 - you can run it on https://dartpad.dartlang.org: `void main() { runApp(MaterialApp(home: RoundedListView2())); }`

Comment: Great seems like you found the solution.. :)